# Stop executing a script?

Tags: php

I call a php function from ajax (addContent):

```
protected $output = array('success'=>0, 'message'=>'There was an error, please try again.');

public function addContent()
{
    $imgName = $this->doSomething();
    $this->doSomethingElse();

    //save imageName to DB
    $this->output['success'] = 1;
    return $output;
}

private function doSomething()
{
    if($imageOk){
       return $imageName;
    }
    else
    {
       $this->output['message'] = 'bad response';
       //how to return output?
    }

}
```

I have made the methods simple for illustrative purposes.

If the method 'doSomething()' has an output of bad response, how can I send this back from the addContent method to ajax? If the output is bad, I want to exit the script and not continue executing doSomethingElse().

Comment: `exit()` will stop the script

Comment: or you can use  `die()`

Comment: _Or_ you can throw an exception, and not catch it, but rather rely on a registered exception handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make `doSomething` return false if it fails validation, and then check for that condition:

```
public function addContent()
{
    $imgName = $this->doSomething();
    if ($imgName === false) {
        return "your error message";
    }
    $this->doSomethingElse();

    //save imageName to DB
    $this->output['success'] = 1;
    return $output;
}

private function doSomething()
{
    if($imageOk){
       return $imageName;
    }
    else
    {
       $this->output['message'] = 'bad response';
       return false;
    }
}
```

You could use either `exit` or `die` as per the comments, but those both kill the script immediately, so unless you were echoing or assigning your error message to a template before calling those functions, your error message wouldn't be returned.

Answer (score 1):

See of it solving (with throwing exception):

> ```
> protected $output = array('success'=>0, 'message'=>'There was an error, please try again.');
>
> public function addContent()
> {
>     try{
>         $imgName = $this->doSomething();
>         $this->doSomethingElse();
>
>         //save imageName to DB
>         $this->output['success'] = 1;
>         return $this->output;
>     }
>     catch(Exception $e){
>         $this->output['success'] = 0;
>         $this->output['message'] = $e->getMessage();
>         return $this->output;
>     }
> }
>
> private function doSomething()
> {
>     if($imageOk){
>        return $imageName;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>        throw new Exception('bad response');
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use exception handling.

```
protected $output = array('success'=>0, 'message'=>'There was an error, please try again.');

public function addContent()
{
    try {
        $imgName = $this->doSomething();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->output['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        return $this->output;
    }
    $this->doSomethingElse();

    //save imageName to DB
    $this->output['success'] = 1;
    return $output;
}

private function doSomething()
{
    if($imageOk) {
       return $imageName;
    }
    else {
       throw new Exception('bad response');
    }

}
```

Comment: @CreatoR beat me to it.